# Embedded ArcOnline map in HTML is not getting centralized on display

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis, esri

I am trying to embed my maps I made on ArcOnline in the HTML and I manage to make tabs to embed them all on one page. However, I am facing some issues which I am not able to understand what is happening with it.
My issues are below:
Every time I use the tabbing method and embed the map on the map on the first tab is centralized in other tabs there it does not get centralized until I click on the home button. I want it to be centralized every time I click on that tab. If I move the map from other tabs to the first tab, they work fine, so I am assuming everything is fine with the map.
Also, the attribute table does not open when the map is in another tab then the first active tab.

My complete html code in the end for reference.
Kindly, let me know is there is a possibility to change this behavior of this map.
I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style> body {font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */ div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1; }

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */ div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: black;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px; }

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */ div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #fff; }

/* Create an active/current tablink class */ div.tab button.active {
    background-color: lightblue; }

/* Style the tab content */ .tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: green; } </style> </head> <body>

<div class="tab">   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMap(event, 'Mapwithlayers')" id="defaultOpen">Mapwithlayers</button>   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMap(event, 'Mapwithfilters')">Mapwithfilters</button>   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMap(event, 'GreyMapLayer')">GreyMapLayer</button>   <div id="Mapwithlayers" class="tabcontent">   <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright"></span>

    <iframe width="100%" height="840px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://arcg.is/2nLnY5A">
    </iframe> </div>

<div id="Mapwithfilters" class="tabcontent">   <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright"></span>

      <iframe width="100%" height="840px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="http://arcg.is/2nLnY5A"></iframe>
      </div>
     <div id="GreyMapLayer" class="tabcontent">   <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright"></span>

      <iframe width="100%" height="840px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="http://un13.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=1f25e4d600ad49539404f8c00c771a5a&amp;extent=-177.7678,-52.1584,172.6076,78.4721&amp;home=true&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;legend=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light"></iframe> </div>

</div> <script> function openMap(evt, mapname) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(mapname).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += "active"; }

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click(); </script>
      </body> </html>
```

Comment: By ArcOnline do you mean ArcGIS Online or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is ArcGIS Online.